# Schema.org itemprop="url" inside anchor object (link)

Tags: theming, entities, uri

I'm trying to use the preprocess function to change the default outpot of links `<a href>` to include Schema.org's `itemprop="url"` **inside the anchor object**, as well as adding a `<span itemprop="title">` to the title of the link. For example:

```
<a href="www.example.com" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Example Title</span></a>
```

*Just to clarify: I want to do this for any link, not just menu or breadcrumb links.

I have managed to do something similar with images using the following code inside my template.php file, but had no luck with adapting it to links:

```
function THEME_preprocess_image(&$vars)
{
$vars["attributes"]["itemprop"] = "image";
}
```

Source can be found [here](http://mechdeveloper.com/blog/solutions-implement-microdata-schemaorg-drupal).

I know that Microdata module might be able to handle that with a few modifications, however, I'd rather do everything manually instead.

I have spent hours searching for solutions but couldn't find any..
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after spending some more time on the matter, I finally found the solution and I am posting it here in case anyone is interested.

Simply put the following code in your template.php file, inside your theme folder:

```
function YOUR-THEME_link($variables) {
  return '<a itemprop="url" href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '><span itemprop="title">' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</span></a>';
}
```

Hope that helps..
Remember to change 'YOUR-THEME' to your theme's name, and don't forget to clear the cache.